# Webpack: ES6 syntax gives Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle, fixed-data-table

I'm trying to use an example of fixed-data-table, and bundle it with webpack.

I'm using babel-loader and my code otherwise bundles without issues.

Running `webpack` points to an error which to my knowledge is a part of ES6 syntax(not ES5) ... The `...` , such as here:

`render() {
        var {sortDir, children, ...props} = this.props;`

the `...props` specifically.

Here's my webpack config:

```
"use strict";

var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './app.js',
        vendor: ["fixed-data-table","react","react-dom","jquery", "bootstrap", "vis", "chart.js"],
    },
    output: { path: "./", filename: 'bundle.js' },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(/* chunkName= */"vendor", /* filename= */"vendor.bundle.js"),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        })
    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.js?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

I'm using es2015 and react as presets and loading with babel-loader. How come it's throwing a syntax error when it's supposed to understand and process ES6 syntax?

Here's my Package.json. Do I need to upgrade some of the versions possibly?

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.3.17",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.3.19",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "^2.4.0",
    "fixed-data-table": "^0.6.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "vis": "^4.17.0"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: Isn't that the ES7 [Rest property](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread/blob/master/Rest.md) feature?

Comment: Really? Facebook have their example here; is that based on ES7? https://github.com/facebook/fixed-data-table/blob/master/examples/SortExample.js

Comment: It's not even ES7 or ES8, it's still an experimental proposal.

Comment: Could wonder why Facebook developers chose to use it, then. But thanks. I solved it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I needed the babel preset to be backwards compatible with ES7.

Solved by:

```
npm install babel-preset-stage-0 --save-dev
```

Followed by adding the preset in the above webpack config:

```
presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0']
```